# How do I run my MySQL database globally so it can connect to my website?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to connect to my MySQL database, it works locally on my computer but when I want to connect it to my website it doesn't work obviously because it's only local. How do I run my database globally so that my website can access it? If there's any helpful link you can send, please do.

Comment: It would be best if you moved it to a server on the Internet.

Comment: 1) set the bind adress to = 0.0.0.0 in the ini file 2) config the firewall that port 3306 is open 3) config the db user to name@ecternalIP or name@% to connect from anywhere

Comment: @Barmar how do I move my server to the internet? Will my database be safe there?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I don't quite get it, is there any link or a tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: you can read this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/

Comment: @CantCode Many of the biggest corporations use services like Amazon RDS, it's perfectly safe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to run a database from your PC you would need to configure your router to have a static external IP address. You would most likely need to talk to your ISP to arrange this, and once in place you would need to update your routers firewall to only allow appropriate traffic into your network.

Although possible, I wouldn't recommend it. It would be far better to get a £5pm droplet from a cloud provider as it will be a lot more reliable, not to mention cheaper!

If you spend a little more you can get a managed database instance in the cloud.

Once you have decided where to run your database, you can update `mysqld.conf` to configure your [bind_address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-conf-options.html#option_mysqlrouter_bind_address). This is the address that MySQL will listen on, and by default will only listen locally. You can change it to your external IP, or to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: You can use a dynamic DNS service if you don't have a static IP.